# python: How do obtain an equation in function of multiple variables? typeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, equation

The following code generates an equation that given the input taken from column 'a' of a given dataframe outputs column 'd' of the same dataframe.

```
d = {'a': [0.1, 0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6], 'b': [0.6, 0.8,0.3,0.4,0.1,0.1],
     'c': [0.7, 0.3,0.9,0.4,1.0,0.2],'d': [1,0,0,1,0,1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

def get_equation(x,y):
    degree = 2
    coefs, res, _, _, _ = np.polyfit(x,y,degree, full = True)
    ffit = np.poly1d(coefs)
    return ffit
print(get_equation(df['a'],df['d']))
```

however, when I want to obtain an equation that outputs 'd' in function of more columns (e.g. 'a' and 'b')
I edit my code this way:

```
d = {'a': [0.1, 0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6], 'b': [0.6, 0.8,0.3,0.4,0.1,0.1],
     'c': [0.7, 0.3,0.9,0.4,1.0,0.2],'d': [1,0,0,1,0,1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

def get_equation(x,y,z): # edited line
    degree = 2
    coefs, res,_ ,_ ,_ ,_ = np.polyfit(x,y,z,degree, full = True) #edited line
    ffit = np.poly1d(coefs)
    return ffit
print(get_equation(df['a'],df['b'],df['d'])) # edited line
```

I obtain the following error:

```
TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-591-0e704e0ab846> in <module>
      8     ffit = np.poly1d(coefs)
      9     return ffit
---> 10 print(get_equation(df['a'],df['b'],df['d'])) # edited line
     11 """
     12 list_df=[]

<ipython-input-591-0e704e0ab846> in get_equation(x, y, z)
      5 def get_equation(x,y,z): # edited line
      6     degree = 2
----> 7     coefs, res,_ ,_ ,_ ,_ = np.polyfit(x,y,z,degree, full = True) #edited line
      8     ffit = np.poly1d(coefs)
      9     return ffit

<__array_function__ internals> in polyfit(*args, **kwargs)

c:\users\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\polynomial.py in polyfit(x, y, deg, rcond, full, w, cov)
    587 
    588     """
--> 589     order = int(deg) + 1
    590     x = NX.asarray(x) + 0.0
    591     y = NX.asarray(y) + 0.0

c:\users\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in wrapper(self)
    139         if len(self) == 1:
    140             return converter(self.iloc[0])
--> 141         raise TypeError(f"cannot convert the series to {converter}")
    142 
    143     wrapper.__name__ = f"__{converter.__name__}__"

TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>
```

How do obtain an equation in function of multiple variables?

Comment: Please post the full traceback so we can see where the error is.

Comment: [`numpy.polyfit(x, y, deg, rcond=None, full=False, w=None, cov=False)`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html#numpy.polyfit) doesn't take z coordinates. Following the link, there is a new API https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/routines.polynomials.html but I don't know if it better fits your needs.

Comment: @tdelaney I edited and included the full error

Comment: Thanks for the edit. The error `--> 589     order = int(deg) + 1` shows what we suspected. The third parameter, `deg`, should be an integer, not a third array.

Comment: but then how come that my first snippet of code works fine? And as soon as I edit it by adding one more variable, I get this error? Shouldn't the error appear even when I only use two columns?

Comment: Look at the call signature and link to docs I posted above. The function takes exactly 2 paramters x and y. You don't get to add a z or subtract a y. I also linked to the newer polynomials documentation which may have more options.